# Linphone iPhone TCP/UDP not receiving incoming calls

Tags: ios, voip, linphone

I am using Linphone Coe 3.10.2 SDK. Server supports TCP and UDP. When TCP is enabled, I cannot call or receive calls at all, it does nothing. When I switch my phone to UDP, every time it says that User is busy, my screen goes to IncomingCallView for one second before connection is broken and it says "User is busy". On Android, it is working normally. And yes, I am not talking about background modes, we have implemented VOIP push services for iOS 10.

Answer (score -2):

I recently have the same problem. All you need to do is set the corret codec. Ask your sip provider what codecs you should